# Crash when destroying weak_ptr, double destruction of weak_ptr's shared_ptr_emplace object

Tags: c++, memory-management, weak-ptr

I'm running into a crash occasionally when the destructor of a weak_ptr is called. This is the precise crash log

```
tests(35405,0x700002602000) malloc: *** error for object 
0x7fcd2010a5b0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The pointer that it is complaining about is the shared_ptr_emplace object that is held inside the weak_ptr. The destructor of the weak_ptr looks like this

```
template<class _Tp>
weak_ptr<_Tp>::~weak_ptr()
{
  if (__cntrl_)
      __cntrl_->__release_weak();
}
```

Its the free of the __cntrl object that is crashing (freed in the call to __release_weak).

Here is a high-level description of what I'm trying to accomplish followed by the crashing function. I'm running USB transactions asynchronously and for every async transaction I return a weak_ptr to an object which allows the client to cancel the async transaction. I call this a `CancelableToken` which also inherits from `enable_shared_this`. The shared_ptr to the token is held by underlying transaction. At the point of the crash the transaction has completed and the shared_ptr to the CancelableToken has been freed and so only a single weak_ptr ref exists (the weak ref from enable_shared_from_this is also removed because the underlying object of the CancelableToken has been freed), the one being held by the calling / waiting function's stack. Here is the method

```
virtual bool ControlSend( uint32_t address, uint32_t value )
{
    bool retval = false;
    shared_ptr<promise<bool>> pPromise = make_shared<promise<bool>>();
    BootCommand cmd( BootCommand::BootCommandWrite, address, value );
    auto fut = pPromise->get_future();
    auto token = SendControlBytesVendorAsync( &cmd, sizeof( cmd ),
                                              [this, pPromise, cmd]( shared_ptr<AUsbTransfer> pTransfer ) {
                                                if( pTransfer->IsSuccessful()) {
                                                  DEBUG_PRINT( "Competed: 0x%x = 0x%x", cmd.address, cmd.value );
                                                  pPromise->set_value( true );
                                                } else {
                                                  DEBUG_PRINT( "ControlSend: Failed to send Control Bytes" );
                                                  pPromise->set_value( false );
                                                }
                                              } );
    if( fut.wait_for( m_timeout ) == future_status::ready ) {
      retval = fut.get();
      DEBUG_PRINT("Transaction Done 0x%x = 0x%x", cmd.address, cmd.value );
    } else {
      LOCK_AND_CANCEL( token );
    }
    DEBUG_PRINT( "Returning, token: %p", &token );
    return retval;
}
```

`SendControlBytesVendorAsync()` is a member function which fires off the async transaction. When the send operation is completed, the passed in function callback is called. The callback is given a shared_ptr to the object that represents the transfer (AUsbTransfer). This Transfer object is the one that owns the shared_ptr to the CancelableToken. When the callback exits, the pTransfer is destroyed and with it the CancelableToken.

The function `ControlSend()` is basically a blocking function that waits for the transaction to complete. Most times the function runs just fine but every once in a while it crashes as I mentioned above. I've tried using the debugger in a case when there is no crash and when it crashes and can't really see a difference. I'm out of ideas on how to debug and could really use some help. If you need me to post any more information, please let me know and I shall.

Comment: Have you tried valgrind?

Comment: No I haven't. Have never used it before. Will start looking into it. Thanks.

Comment: so, it seems the second-last weak_ptr believes to be the last one ... the first thing I'd check is proper enable_shared_from_this usage (are you invoking it during destruction ? do you use aliasing shared_ptr ? if you have doubts, you may use a C++17 compiler: in C++17 shared_from_this() throws if used unproperly )

Comment: So I finally resolved the issue. One of the libraries I wrote had --stdlib=libc++ as a compiler flag. This was not present in other components of my project. removing this helped. I'm not sure why though. I would assume that Cmake would select libc++ on darwin by default and the explicit stdlib option would be redundant. ie. I expect all the components to be using libc++. The way it is currently leads me to believe that cmake is linking my libs to libstdc++ when no explicit std lib is specified. Is that actually true ?